# Stop IIS 7.5 Application Pool Recycling

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, application-pool, recycle

How do stop application pools from recycling in IIS 7.5?

I have configured the following settings:

```
ProcessModel -> Idle Time-out (minutes) = 0
Recycling -> Regular Time Intervals (minutes) = 0
```

Are these settings enought to stop an application pool from recycling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that should be ok assuming you also use Private Memory Limit = 0.
There are still reasons an AppPool could recycle, such as when adding a new Global Module, it will require to be recycled so configuration changes take effect, but you can also disable that using the "Disable Recycling on Configuratoin Changes".

Finally if you are running ASP.NET you should consider that still AppDomains will recycle when changes in config (such as web.config) happen. But that should not affect the AppPool per'se only the ASP.NET applications running in it (such as Session State), but again it depends on why you ask this question if this is important or not.

Comment: is Stop IIS 7.5 Application Pool Recycling harmful??