# asp.net 4.0 update database from xml automatically daily at 12am

Tags: asp.net, xml, datetime, c#-4.0, automation

Basically I want to update tours table in the database from XML automatically daily at specific time. 
For instance System Daily update my database table from XML at 12AM.
Is it possible with ASP.NET 4.0 if yes then how i can implement this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use windows scheduled task instead of asp.net for repeating tasks.

you can create console aplication and run it using task sheduler

- [Schedule SyncToy to Run Automatically With Task Scheduler in Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25046/schedule-synctoy-to-run-automatically-with-task-scheduler-in-windows-7/)

if you want to do it using asp.net try Quartz.net

- [Quartz.net setup in an asp.net website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245975/quartz-net-setup-in-an-asp-net-website)