# How to trigger a task (like email) automatically according to the appointment Date/Time set in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Suppose I have an entity:

```
    public class Appointment
    {
        public DateTime AppointmentDateTime {get;set}
        public string CustomerName {get;set;}
        public string CustomerEmail {get;set;}
    }
```

How can I schedule an email to be sent to customer 2 Hours before AppointmentDateTime Automatically? Also is it possible to reschedule the email time when AppointmentDateTime is changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to run scheduled tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542804/best-way-to-run-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: There are many posts explaining how to create a scheduler but I couldn't find one which uses datetime from the entity itself.

Comment: How would a third-party library understand your entities? You'll have to write some code to link your business logic to those libraries.

Comment: They don't actually need to understand the entities but I am looking for a way schedule the jobs accordingly. Like If I could schedule a job when I create a new 'Appointment' and reschedule if I change the appointment time.

Comment: You can do that, but you'll have to write code to do so.

Comment: Yes I understand that and I am trying to configure quartz.net but I find it's documentation a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Quarts.Net. this allows you to preform actions at selected times. I am not sure if you can be as granular as run this exact email at this exact time but you can get it to run a job every 5 mins (or faster) to check if any emails are scheduled to be sent and then send them.

I use the second approach and it works well for me where i run a job to update accounts and a different job to send out batch emails (if any are waiting) as a result of that.

Comment: I am actually trying to configure quartz according to my requirements but honestly I am finding it's documentation a bit difficult. Can you direct me towards an MVC 4 tutorial for quartz.net ?

Comment: this is a pretty good  example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245975/quartz-net-setup-in-an-asp-net-website