# Wcf Service be opened even if website is not opened in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I initiated Wcf Service in website initialization procedure.

When first time that site is opened, this service will be initiated on specific port. The Wcf service will be available as long website is opened on browser. when browser is closed, after awhile WCF service will be closed.

How can I keep service open and alive even if site is closed on browser?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain on what it is you're asking, so I'm making a few assumptions:

1. You're running an ASP.NET website in IIS
2. You're hosting a WCF service in that website

If those assumptions hold, then what you're seeing is the app pool being recycled, which is where your web app is unloaded and as a result, your service stops.

See: [Stop IIS 7.5 Application Pool Recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156925/stop-iis-7-5-application-pool-recycling) for some info on how to prevent this.

Alternatively, you probably shouldn't be hosting a WCF service inside an ASP.NET application for this very reason.

Instead, see this: [How to host a WCF service in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis) which has WCF specific instructions.

Comment: Thanks,
your assumptions are right. let me check your links.

Comment: I didn't try to host wcf on IIS due to I need to use many dlls of website.
when site is initiated by user for first time, some variables and modules initialized that will be used in wcf.
let assume we host wcf on IIS and application pool recycled.
I think I still have problem because all initiated variable will be lost. Am I right?

Comment: Can I set to auto start wcf after recycling in IIS or code?